# Yii2 rule which would allow all the letters (including special ones), but without special characters?

Tags: regex, yii2

I have a problem here. My `username` rule allowing to enter only letters without special characters, but could someone help me to make that it would allow letters (including special letters), but without special characters?

F.e:

Test - good,
Tęęęst - good,
Test2 - bad.

My rule is:

```
['username', 'match',
   'pattern' => '/[a-z]+$/',
]
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: What are "special characters" to you?

Comment: Ehm, it's all the $#$%&&*<> and etc. I just want my field would allow just only letters (including ĄČĘĖĮŠŲ and others)

Comment: Do you also need to support combining marks/diacritics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this but remember it does not work on the client side since JavaScript does not support unicode regex flags (at least without special plugins):

```
['username', 'match', 'pattern' => '/^\p{L}+$/u']
```

This allows letters (in **all** languages) only.