# Regex which would allow to enter just letters in all languages?

Tags: regex, yii2

I have a problem here. I know there were a lot of questions related to this, but I couldn't find any useful information. I need to write `regular expression` which would allow for user to enter just only letters in all the languages without special characters (f.e `#@#%^&43`) and etc.

I've tried this, but this expression doesn't allow to enter any letters or special characters:

```
/^\p{L}+$/u
```

And this: this allows to enter just only letters, but without `ąčęėįš` :(

```
/[a-z]+$/
```

My rule is:

```
['name', 'match',
    'pattern' => '^\p{L}+$',
],
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: See [Yii2 rule which would allow all the letters (including special ones), but without special characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43469793/yii2-rule-which-would-allow-all-the-letters-including-special-ones-but-withou). The `/^\p{L}+$/u` will validate any string that has 1 or more letters.

Comment: As you can see, my used regular expressions is exact as in that post, today i've tried that, but it didn't worked, so

Comment: Did you run the validation on the *server* side? It is written in the answer there you cannot pass this pattern to the JS regex engine.

Comment: Ehm, nah, haven't done that yet. Could you tell me how the validation should be done?

Comment: "If you want to turn off client-side validation completely, you may configure the `yii\widgets\ActiveForm::$enableClientValidation` property to be false. You may also turn off client-side validation of individual input fields by configuring their `yii\widgets\ActiveField::$enableClientValidation` property to be false. When *enableClientValidation* is configured at both the input field level and the form level, the former will take precedence." ([source](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html))

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html

This has a list of all options for \p, pick the one that suits your need, or combine them like `^[\p{L}\p{N}]+$`. Valid for server-side PCRE (PHP), not frontend (JS).